# How to load an image asynchronously from URI in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, mobile, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my current code for loading the Image:

```
System.Uri uri;
System.Uri.TryCreate (imageURI, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
_companyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri (uri);
```

The problem is that the whole program has to wait for this task to complete, I would like to load the image asynchronously but I can't work out how to create an image source asynchronously.

Comment: See http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_an_image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grab the data asynchronously and assign it to your Source once it is done.

```
System.Uri uri;
System.Uri.TryCreate(imageURI, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
Task<ImageSource> result = Task<ImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageSource.FromUri(uri));
_companyImage.Source = await result;
```

Comment: Is there any benefit swapping the third line for `Task<UriImageSource> result = Task<UriImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => new UriImageSource { Uri = uri, CachingEnabled = true, CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0) });`

Comment: @RichardD Using ImageSource.FromUri() is the same thing as using new UriImageSource. It defaults CachingEnabled to true and CacheValidity to one day. Swapping that line would just change the cache time from one day to three days. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

Comment: it said expression not supported

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the `Image.Source` property to a URI and let Xamarin.Forms do the work for you (per ["Working with Images" in Xamarin.Forms docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Downloading_Images)).

### Example

```
var someImage = new Image() {
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
    Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/branding/assets/xamagon.png")),
};
```

Comment: This is pretty what I was doing already. Was I already loading the image asynchronously then? Or is this subtly different?

Comment: If you are doing the `ImageSource.FromUri` process, there's a good chance you were already doing it asynchronously (an alternative being `ImageSource.FromResource` for a local image). You could test it by putting your device into airplane mode and loading whatever page has your URI-sourced image.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that this `FromUri` system will cache things locally for you. If you load it first with the network, it may still work on the disconnected request.

Comment: Where in the documentation link you sent does it say it's loading asynchronously?

Comment: @jbyrd the docs referenced was regarding how it was done, not that the docs explicitly say asynchronous. It absolutely is async; it's just not mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Set your url to Source proprty or bind from viewmodel

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

```
<Image Source="yoururl"  Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the special case that you're trying to use a ContentUri on Android (e.g. `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/18/photo`), this is the required incantation:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(str);
_companyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri));
```